# flask-pyoidc token_auth 403

Tags: python, flask

I'm running flask-pyoidc examples from their site. I'm stuck trying to hit endpoint protected with token_auth with Authorization:Bearer.

I got the access_token correctly on /api1. Now I paste this access token to YARC client with header

```
Authorization:Bearer<access_token>
```

But keep getting 403 on /api2.
To mention, I'm running this on Werkzeug development server and using Keycloak. I tried many times pretty much the same thing all over again, cleaning cookies and just making sure I'm not making any errors. I'm starting to think maybe it is about Keycloak but I think it is all enabled correctly for Authorization grant flow.

```
import flask
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_pyoidc import OIDCAuthentication
from flask_pyoidc.provider_configuration import ProviderConfiguration, ClientMetadata, ProviderMetadata
from flask_pyoidc.user_session import UserSession


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(
    OIDC_REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:5000/callback',
    SECRET_KEY = "xyzrandom"
)

# Static Client Registration
client_metadata = ClientMetadata(
    client_id='myappclient',
    client_secret='XXXYYY',
    post_logout_redirect_uris=['http://localhost:5000/logout'])

provider_metadata = ProviderMetadata(
    issuer='http://XXXXXX:8080/realms/myapp',
    authorization_endpoint="http://XXXXXX:8080/realms/myapp/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
    token_endpoint= "http://XXXXXX:8080/realms/myapp/protocol/openid-connect/token",
    introspection_endpoint='http://XXXXXX:8080/realms/myapp/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect',
    userinfo_endpoint='http://XXXXXX:8080/realms/myapp/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo',
    end_session_endpoint='http://XXXXXX:8080/realms/myapp/protocol/openid-connect/logout',
    jwks_uri='http://XXXXXX:8080/realms/myapp/protocol/openid-connect/certs',
    registration_endpoint='http://XXXXXX:8080/realms/myapp/clients-registrations/openid-connect'

)

provider_config = ProviderConfiguration(client_metadata=client_metadata, provider_metadata=provider_metadata)

auth = OIDCAuthentication({'default': provider_config}, app)
auth.init_app(app)


@app.route('/api1')
@auth.oidc_auth('default')
def api1():
    user_session = UserSession(flask.session)
    return jsonify(access_token=user_session.access_token,
                   id_token=user_session.id_token,
                   userinfo=user_session.userinfo)

@app.route('/api2')
@auth.token_auth('default')
def api2():
    current_token_identity = auth.current_token_identity
    return "Something"
```